# Windows Server Hyper-V Configuration and Hardware Requirements

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, virtual-machines, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I plan to buy a windows server machine as a part of an academic project. In this project I plan to use one windows server having multiple virtual servers. At this step, I am writing a hardware and software purchasing requirements which would change the cost of the project.

The responsibilities of virtual servers are listed as below.

1-Virtual Machine: Windows- Firewall Software is installed on this virtual machine. 
2-Virtual Machine: Windows OS- Database server
3-Virtual Machine: Web Server
4-Virtual Machine: Linux- Would host a server application
5-Virtual Machine: Kali Linux- Would be used to make penetration tests to the other 4 virtual servers.
6- Virtual Machine: Would host exchange server
7- There may be other virtual requirements such as Active directory

I haven't used virtualization for a while and I want to make a correct purchase. The performance of the machine is not a big problem cause the all thing would be used only for test purposes not in a live environment. Small database and web applications will be installed for test purposes only.

My questions are:
1-How many virtual machines can I define at most on Windows server OS?
2-Can I actually use the first virtual machine as a firewall and prevent access to other virtual machines from the internet based on firewall rules (not always). 
3-How many network cards should I have for this configuration? I was to learn if I need a separate network card for each virtual machine? (which would be too costy) or may be one network card for virtual machine 1 which would act as firewall and one for the rest? 
4-Should I have to buy a Hyper-V license separately ( I remember that windows server comes with Hyper-V manager with at most 5  virtual machines but I am not sure)
5-Should I have to buy any other license or other thing?

I am open to any thoughts which may improve this configuration. My budget is not very high so the most economical solution would be perfect for me.

Thank you for your valuable time and happy holidays.

Ferda

Answer (score 1):

1. [1024 VMs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/compute/hyper-v/plan/plan-for-hyper-v-scalability-in-windows-server-2016) per Hyper-V Host.
2. Sure. Why wouldn't you be able to?
3. As many as you need.
4. Contact your license reseller. There is no such thing as a Hyper-V license, but there are numerous ways to license the guests.
5. How can we tell you whether or not you need to license anything without any requirements, insight into your current licenses, or anything else. Contact your license reseller for this type of discussion.

Comment: Hi @MDMarra, thank you for your answer. What do you mean as many as you need. ? I updated my 3. question I was trying to ask if I need a separate network card for each virtual machine? (which would be too costy) or may be one network card for virtual machine 1 which would act as firewall and one for the rest? Can you please clarify your answer?

Comment: No. It depends on your networking requirements. Maybe you should consider hiring a consultant with Hyper-V experience to help you Architect this.

Comment: we don't have a budget to hire a virtualization consultant :)